# Update Google Play Services

Tags: android

Ребята, на версиях Api22 и выше работает всё хорошо,но на ранних версиях пишет "Update Google Play services"
Посмотрел версию сервисов в эмуляторе и увидел 9.2.+.
У меня же в buidle.gradle стоит 10.2.0. Пытался поменять её на более раннюю,не получается,выбивает ошибку,мол смените версию на более раннюю. 
Как можно решить данный вопрос?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "by.ittech.test_chat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}














apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Скорее всего нужно обновить сервайс на самом устройстве, чтобы библиотеки в вашем приложении могли работать на нем.

Comment: @а другие версии есть?Ибо я просто не смогу работать с устройствами ниже Api 22